# How to recreate the Fragment from refresh button of ActionBar?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar, android-fragmentactivity

I made tabs in my android app using FragmentActivity and Fragments. I have an ActionBar for all Fragments which has a refresh button. I want to refresh the specific fragment from where i press the refresh button of ActionBar. Any idea about that? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just recreate the fragment by replacing the existing one, check this link out.

[Fragment Transaction](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Transactions)

[FragmentActionBar](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#ActionBar)

Or am I missing something in your question? Cheers.

Comment: what should i do first to access that refresh button of actionbar in my specific fragment. for example if i am in third fragment then how can i access the refresh button only for that fragment. I tried a lot but can not access that refresh button press action outside FragmentActivity

Comment: Wait, you want to access the action button from a fragment inside a fragmentactivity?

Comment: I think best is that if i can access the action button inside a fragment.

Comment: Why not just set what the button does inside `onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)`? But if you really wanted to get the `MenuItem` have you tried `MenuItem menuItem = (MenuItem) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.refresh);` then `menuItem.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new MenuItem.OnMenuItemClickListener() { });`

Comment: i tried @Override
 public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
     // Handle item selection
  System.out.println("refresh clicked");
  
     return true;
 } in fragment but its not working. i do not see any System out

Comment: No.. That function goes in the Activity, not the Fragment. As for Fragment, if you really want to do it there, try the other Approach I described.

Comment: I get this exception: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.android.internal.view.menu.ActionMenuItemView cannot be cast to android.view.MenuItem on line MenuItem menuItem = (MenuItem) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.refresh_item);

Comment: Oh yes, you are correct, I had the same issue, just jogged my memory, I ended up implementing a communication interface, or you can use this (which seems to be a better option) http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#ActionBar In any case, both solutions are in that page.

Comment: So in android there is not simple way to get an actionbar menuitem in a fragment. Thats sucks.

Comment: There is an easy way and there is the right way :D  Feel free to accept. Cheers.

Comment: Please edit your answer with developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#ActionBar link so i can accept it as correct answer. and Thank you so much for helping.